# TabController not syncing with BottomNavigationItems on ios (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, dart

I have the following code which uses the `flutter_platform_widgets` package to render tabs native to the platform.

So, on android I want to have the tabs at the top and on ios I want to have the tabs at the bottom.

On Android the tabcontroller and the tabs syncs perfectly and everything works well.

But, on iOS the tabController is not syncing with the bottom navigation items. If I click on a bottom navigation item the tabController will not animate to the index, then some other time it animates to the index. It's kind of on and off on the ios.

If I swipe right or left on the body, the bottom navigation tabs still don't pick up the latest index from the tab controller on ios.

So, in summary it's been an on and off behaviour on the ios version but everything works perfectly on android.

Here is my full code as is:

```
import 'package:easy_localization/easy_localization.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_platform_widgets/flutter_platform_widgets.dart';
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';
import '../beans/pair.dart';
import '../extensions/target_platform.dart';

class MarketPlaceScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const MarketPlaceScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MarketPlaceScreenState createState() => _MarketPlaceScreenState();
}

class _MarketPlaceScreenState extends State<MarketPlaceScreen>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  final List<Widget> _tabContents = [
    Text("most_popular".tr()),
    Text("cheapest".tr())
  ];
  final List<Pair<String, Widget>> _tabTitleAndIcons = [
    Pair("most_popular".tr(), const FaIcon(FontAwesomeIcons.arrowTrendUp)),
    Pair("cheapest".tr(), const FaIcon(FontAwesomeIcons.dollarSign))
  ];
  late TabController _tabController;

  _tabChangedHandler() {}

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _tabController = TabController(
      length: _tabContents.length,
      vsync: this,
    );
    _tabController.addListener(_tabChangedHandler);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _tabController.removeListener(_tabChangedHandler);
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return PlatformScaffold(
      backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.background,
      iosContentPadding: true,
      appBar: PlatformAppBar(
        material: (_, __) => MaterialAppBarData(
          bottom: TabBar(
            controller: _tabController,
            labelColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
            indicatorColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
            unselectedLabelColor: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyMedium?.color,
            tabs: _tabTitleAndIcons
                .asMap()
                .map((index, value) {
              return MapEntry(
                index,
                Tab(
                  text: _tabTitleAndIcons[index].first,
                  icon: _tabTitleAndIcons[index].second,
                ),
              );
            })
                .values
                .toList(),
          ),
        ),
        title: Text("market_place".tr()),
        trailingActions: <Widget>[
          PlatformTextButton(
            cupertino: (_, __) => CupertinoTextButtonData(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
            ),
            child: Text(
              "done".tr().toUpperCase(),
            ),
            onPressed: () {},
          ),
        ],
      ),
      bottomNavBar: defaultTargetPlatform.isAnAppleDevice()
          ? PlatformNavBar(
        currentIndex: _tabController.index,
        items: _tabTitleAndIcons
            .asMap()
            .map((index, value) {
          return MapEntry(
            index,
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              label: _tabTitleAndIcons[index].first,
              icon: _tabTitleAndIcons[index].second,
            ),
          );
        })
            .values
            .toList(),
        itemChanged: (newIndex) {
          _tabController.animateTo(newIndex);
        },
      )
          : null,
      body: TabBarView(
        controller: _tabController,
        children: const [
          PopularMarketPlaceTab(),
          CheapestTab(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class PopularMarketPlaceTab extends StatelessWidget {
  const PopularMarketPlaceTab({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Center(
      child: Text(
        'Patronize popular products',
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CheapestTab extends StatelessWidget {
  const CheapestTab({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Center(
      child: Text(
        "Patronize affordable products",
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

What could be wrong?

Thank you